# WARNING: Missing 'go_package' option

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, proto

Im getting the following error once i run the protocol command to generate pb.go file
But I can generate the pb.go file. how do I mitigate the following error

```
Missing 'go_package' option in "job.proto",
please specify it with the full Go package path as
a future release of protoc-gen-go will require this be specified.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Import path" is the path another package would use to import the generated code, e.g. github.com/me/myproject/model or You can simply define the import path based on your preference.

You can simply define your optional import path as follows

```
option go_package = ".;<Your_Import_path>";
```

For example, we can assume the package path as "/pub", So the statement as follows.

```
option go_package = ".;pub";
```

Then you can simply execute the *protoc* command to generate the *pb.go* file

```
protoc -I=<ABS_PATH_OUTPUT_DIR> --go_out=<ABS_PATH_PROTO_FILE>
```